# Typoscript: How to create a popup-dialog that controls a browser-/useragent-switch

Tags: browser, popup, typo3, typoscript

I have a question regarding Typocript, because I want to realize the follwoing in Typo3:

- A user visits a website (with his IPhone) that is based on Typo3 (Version 4.3)
- The user gets a popup dialog where he can choose whether to visit the 'standard'-website, or the website that is optimized for the IPhone view
- The user makes his selection and is redirected to the mobile or standard website

This is what happens at the moment:

- When the user visits the website using the IPhone device, he is automatically redirected to the mobile-website
- When the user visits the website using any other Browser or device, he is redirected to the standard website

I realized this using a Useragent-Switch:

```
[useragent = *iPhone*]
page >
page = PAGE
page.meta.REFRESH = 0;index.php?id=xx
[end]
```

If there is no possibility to realize it directly in Typoscript: Does anyone know how to realize this using an self created extension, that calls a popup dialog and redirects the user afterwards to a page-id?

Thanks in advance,
Cheeesi

Answer (score 1):

If your user is using an iphone, he might not like a real popup window.

I'd use your typoscript condition to add a javascript file:

```
[useragent = *iPhone*]
page.includeJS.popup = fileadmin/.../popup.js
[end]
```

Comment: That answer came to my mind, too. If you don't like the looks of js alert boxes, you can think about injecting an overlay container into the DOM by your javascript. Remember to store a cookie or append a GET parameter after the choice so the user is not asked everytime he opens a page on your site.